# Бесконечная прокрутка карусели

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

Всем привет, пробую создать бесконечную карусель, при переключении слайда(допустим transition -1500px) с последнего на первый я хочу без плавного перехода сбросить transition в ноль

```
 transitionDuration = '0s'
 transform = 'translateX(0px)'
```

и сразу же плавно переключить на следующий слайд

```
transitionDuration = '0.5s'
transform = 'translateX(-500px)'
```

Но срабатывает просто плавный переход c -1500 до -500

Код слайдера:

```js
class SliderNth {
  constructor() {
    this.slider = document.querySelector('.nth-item-slider');
    this.slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-slide');
    this.sliderContainer = document.querySelector('.nth-item-slider-wrapper');
    this.controls = this.slider.querySelector('.nth-slides-control-wrapper');
    this.resolutionSettings = [
      {
        width: 425,
        num: 1
      },
      {
        width: 1240,
        num: 3
      },
      {
        width: 1440,
        num: 4
      },
      {
        width: 1980,
        num: 5
      }

    ]
  }

  init() {
    this.slides.forEach((item, i) => {
      this.createControl(i)
      this.activeSlide.classList.add('active-point');
    });

    this.width = this.slider.offsetWidth;
    this.setSlideWidth();

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this.width = this.slider.offsetWidth;
      this.setSlideWidth();
    });



    this.unwind()

  }

  unwind() {
    this.intervalSlide = setTimeout(this.changeSlide.bind(this) , 2000);
  }
  createControl(id) {
    let cnt = document.createElement('span');
    cnt.dataset.id = id;
    if (id === 0) this.activeSlide = cnt;
    cnt.addEventListener('click', this.changeSlide.bind(this))
    this.controls.append(cnt);
  }
  changeSlide(){

    clearTimeout(this.intervalSlide);
    this.activeSlide.classList.remove('active-point');
    this.sliderContainer.style.transitionDuration = '0.2s'
    if (event) {

      this.activeSlide = event.target;
        this.sliderContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${(-this.activeSlide.dataset['id'] - 1) * this.translateSlide}px)`;
    } else if ( this.controls.children[parseInt(this.activeSlide.dataset['id']) + 1]) {

      this.activeSlide =  this.controls.children[parseInt(this.activeSlide.dataset['id']) + 1];
        this.sliderContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${(-this.activeSlide.dataset['id'] - 1) * this.translateSlide}px)`;
    } else {
      this.sliderContainer.style.transitionDuration = '0s'
      this.sliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(0px)'
      this.activeSlide = this.controls.children[0];
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.sliderContainer.style.transitionDuration = '0.2s'
      this.sliderContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${(-this.activeSlide.dataset['id'] - 1) * this.translateSlide}px)`;
      }, 10)
      

    }

    this.activeSlide.classList.add('active-point');
    this.unwind();
    // this.sliderContainer.style.transitionDuration = '0.2s'
  }
  setSlideWidth(){
    if (this.currentSettings) {

      for (let i = 0; i < this.num - 1; i++) {
        this.sliderContainer.removeChild(this.sliderContainer.lastElementChild);
      }
      this.sliderContainer.removeChild(this.sliderContainer.firstElementChild);

    }
    this.currentSettings = this.resolutionSettings.find(item => this.width <= item.width);



    if (this.currentSettings?.width == 425) {
      this.num = this.currentSettings.num;
      this.slides.forEach(item => {
        item.style.marginLeft = '0px';
        item.style.minWidth = this.width + 'px' ;
        this.translateSlide = this.width;
      });

    } else {
      this.num = this.currentSettings.num;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.num - 1; i++) {
        let cln_first = this.slides[i].cloneNode(true)
        this.sliderContainer.append(cln_first)
      }
      let cln_last = this.slides[this.slides.length - 1].cloneNode(true)
      this.sliderContainer.prepend(cln_last)

      this.slides = [...this.sliderContainer.children];
      this.slides.forEach((item, i)=> {
        item.style.marginLeft = i != 0 ? '10px' : '0px';
        item.style.minWidth = (this.width - 10 * this.num - 1) / this.num + 'px';
        this.translateSlide = (this.width - 10 * this.num - 1) / this.num + 10;
      });

    }
  }
  sliDeToInitPosition(){
    this.sliderContainer
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (!document.querySelector('.nth-item-slider')) return;
  let sliderBox = new SliderNth();
  sliderBox.init();
})
```

```css
.nth-item-slider{
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.nth-item-slider-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  transition:all 0.2 ease-out;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.slider-slide{
  /* min-width: 400px; */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-slide img{
  width: 100%;
}
.slider-slide:nth-child(n + 2){
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.slides-control-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 64px;
    left: 5%;

}
.slides-control-wrapper span , .nth-slides-control-wrapper span{
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #171E37;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slides-control-wrapper span.active-point,
.nth-slides-control-wrapper span.active-point{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #E26969 0%, #E73331 100%);
}
.nth-slides-control-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="nth-item-slider">
    <div class="nth-item-slider-wrapper">
      <div class="slider-slide">
        1
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-slide">
        2
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-slide">
        3
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-slide">
        4
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-slide">
        5
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-slide">
        6
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-slide">
        7
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-slide">
        8
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-slide">
        9
        <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nth-slides-control-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
```

Первый вопрос, есть ли более красивый способ сделать карусель, что мне надо для этого переделать.
Второй вопрос, почему таким образом работает transition, что можно поменять, чтоб код заработал.

UPD: Второрой вопрос решил, просто закинул часть кода в setTimeout, остается только понять на сколько этот код имеет право на жизнь и есть ли более красивые способы реализации

Answer (score 1):

```js
class SliderNth {
  constructor() {
    this.slider = document.querySelector('.nth-item-slider');
    this.slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-slide');
    this.sliderContainer = document.querySelector('.nth-item-slider-wrapper');
    this.controls = this.slider.querySelector('.nth-slides-control-wrapper');
    this.resolutionSettings = [{
        width: 425,
        num: 1
      },
      {
        width: 1240,
        num: 3
      },
      {
        width: 1440,
        num: 4
      },
      {
        width: 1980,
        num: 5
      }

    ]
  }

  init() {
    this.slides.forEach((item, i) => {
      this.createControl(i)
      this.activeSlide.classList.add('active-point');
    });

    this.width = this.slider.offsetWidth;
    this.setSlideWidth();

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this.width = this.slider.offsetWidth;
      this.setSlideWidth();
    });



    this.unwind()

  }

  unwind() {
    this.intervalSlide = setTimeout(this.changeSlide.bind(this), 2000);
  }
  createControl(id) {
    let cnt = document.createElement('span');
    cnt.dataset.id = id;
    if (id === 0) this.activeSlide = cnt;
    cnt.addEventListener('click', this.changeSlide.bind(this))
    this.controls.append(cnt);
  }
  changeSlide() {

    clearTimeout(this.intervalSlide);
    this.activeSlide.classList.remove('active-point');
    this.sliderContainer.style.transitionDuration = '0.2s'
    if (event) {

      this.activeSlide = event.target;
      this.sliderContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${(-this.activeSlide.dataset['id'] - 1) * this.translateSlide}px)`;
    } else if (this.controls.children[parseInt(this.activeSlide.dataset['id']) + 1]) {

      this.activeSlide = this.controls.children[parseInt(this.activeSlide.dataset['id']) + 1];
      this.sliderContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${(-this.activeSlide.dataset['id'] - 1) * this.translateSlide}px)`;
    } else {
      console.log('Обнулился');
      this.sliderContainer.style.transitionDuration = '0s'
      this.sliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(0px)'
      this.activeSlide = this.controls.children[0];
      //this.sliderContainer.style.transitionDuration = '0.2s'
      this.sliderContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${(-this.activeSlide.dataset['id'] - 1) * this.translateSlide}px)`;

    }

    this.activeSlide.classList.add('active-point');
    this.unwind();
    // this.sliderContainer.style.transitionDuration = '0.2s'
  }
  setSlideWidth() {
    if (this.currentSettings) {

      for (let i = 0; i < this.num - 1; i++) {
        this.sliderContainer.removeChild(this.sliderContainer.lastElementChild);
      }
      this.sliderContainer.removeChild(this.sliderContainer.firstElementChild);

    }
    this.currentSettings = this.resolutionSettings.find(item => this.width <= item.width);



    if (this.currentSettings?.width == 425) {
      this.num = this.currentSettings.num;
      this.slides.forEach(item => {
        item.style.marginLeft = '0px';
        item.style.minWidth = this.width + 'px';
        this.translateSlide = this.width;
      });

    } else {
      this.num = this.currentSettings.num;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.num - 1; i++) {
        let cln_first = this.slides[i].cloneNode(true)
        this.sliderContainer.append(cln_first)
      }
      let cln_last = this.slides[this.slides.length - 1].cloneNode(true)
      this.sliderContainer.prepend(cln_last)

      this.slides = [...this.sliderContainer.children];
      this.slides.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.style.marginLeft = i != 0 ? '10px' : '0px';
        item.style.minWidth = (this.width - 10 * this.num - 1) / this.num + 'px';
        this.translateSlide = (this.width - 10 * this.num - 1) / this.num + 10;
      });

    }
  }
  sliDeToInitPosition() {
    this.sliderContainer
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (!document.querySelector('.nth-item-slider')) return;
  let sliderBox = new SliderNth();
  sliderBox.init();
})
```

```css
.nth-item-slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nth-item-slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2 ease-out;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.slider-slide {
  /* min-width: 400px; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-slide:nth-child(n + 2) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.slides-control-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 64px;
  left: 5%;
}

.slides-control-wrapper span,
.nth-slides-control-wrapper span {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #171E37;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slides-control-wrapper span.active-point,
.nth-slides-control-wrapper span.active-point {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #E26969 0%, #E73331 100%);
}

.nth-slides-control-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="nth-item-slider">
  <div class="nth-item-slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider-slide">
      1
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-slide">
      2
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-slide">
      3
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-slide">
      4
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-slide">
      5
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-slide">
      6
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-slide">
      7
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-slide">
      8
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-slide">
      9
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/1-19951_m.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nth-slides-control-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не подходит, теряется плавность, с плавностью уже решил, интересно на сколько вообще это нормальная реализация

Comment: @Alexandr >с последнего на первый я хочу без плавного перехода сбросить transition в ноль... Так вы же и хотели без плавного перехода.

Comment: видимо я плохо описал свою цель